# Old Ruby version is overriding new Ruby Install

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I'm trying to update Ruby from 2.0 to 2.4. The installation went through, but when I type in terminal ruby -v I'm shown the following:

ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]

I have no clue on how override the old version. Any assistance would be awesome.

Comment: What Ruby manager are you using?

Comment: I am using ruby-install and chruby. It's simplest of them all IMO. Check out this: https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install and this: https://github.com/postmodern/chruby

Comment: What's the output of `chruby`? Do you see both ruby versions listed?

Comment: Thank you for the information and recommendations. I was able to upgrade Ruby successfully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To make ruby 2.4.0 as your default ruby version :

```
rvm --default use 2.4.0
```

Now , `ruby -v` will show ruby-2.4.0

If not installed already then Run:

```
rvm install ruby-2.4.0
```

Reference : [rvm documentation](https://rvm.io/rubies/default)

In case of [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby), Run

```
chruby ruby-2.4.0
```

to make ruby-2.4.0 as default version

Comment: OP uses chruby, not rvm.